# Dict key getting overwritten when created in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to create individual dictionary entries while looping through some input data. Part of the data is used for the key, while a different part is used as the value associated with that key.  I'm running into a problem (due to Python's "everything is an object, and you reference that object" operations method) with this as ever iteration through my loop alters the key set in previous iterations, thus overwriting the previously set value, instead of creating a new dict key and setting it with its own value.

```
popcount = {}
for oneline of datafile:
  if oneline[:3] == "POP":
    dat1, dat2, dat3, dat4, dat5, dat6 = online.split(":")
    datid = str.join(":", [dat2, dat3])
    if datid in popcount:
      popcount[datid] += int(dat4)
    else:
      popcount = { datid : int(dat4) }
```

This iterates over seven lines of data (`datafile` is a list containing that information) and should create four separate keys for `datid`, each with their own value.  However, what ends up happening is that only the last value for `datid` exist in the dictionary when the code is run.  That happens to be the one that has duplicates, and they get summed properly (so, at least i know *that* part of the code works, but the other key entries just are ... gone.

The data is read from a file, is colon (`:`) separated, and treated like a string even when its numeric (thus the `int()` call in the `if datid in popcount`).

What am I missing/doing wrong here? So far I haven't been able to find anything that helps me out on this one (though you folks have answered a **lot** of other Python questions i've run into, even if you didn't know it). I know why its failing; or, i think i do -- it *is* because when I update the value of `datid` the key gets pointed to the new `datid` value object even though I don't want it to, correct? I just don't know how to fix or work around this behavior.  To be honest, its the one thing I dislike about working in Python (hopefully once I grok it, I'll like it better; until then...).

Comment: Every time you find a new `datid` value, you are explicitly throwing away all of the previously collected data, by replacing the entire `popcount` dictionary with a new one containing only the new item.  The way you add a new value to an existing dictionary is `popcount[datid] = dat4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your last line

```
popcount = { datid : int(dat4) } # This does not do what you want
```

This creates a new `dict` and assignes it to `popcount`, throwing away your previous data.

What you want to do is add an entry to your `dict` instead:

```
popcount[datid] = int(dat4)
```

Comment: I could have sworn this was how I started and it was throwing an error, but its working now, so thank you for the help.